# What is the significance of the 700 left handed men?

Tags: judges

> Judges 20:16 (KJV) Among all this  people there  were seven hundred  chosen men lefthanded: every one could sling stones at an hairbreadth, and not miss. (KJV)

What is the significance of these men being left handed?